# Is it possible to use the same cron jobs for different subdirectories within the same domain name

Tags: php, cron

I am working on a project in which I want to use the same cron job for different subdirectories within the same domain name like

> www.abc.com/first
>
> www.abc.com/second
>
> www.abc.com/third

How can i do this can anyone please tell me?

Comment: That's not possible unless if your domains are in the same server.

Comment: all subdirectories are on the same server... edited the question please check once...

Answer (score 1):

Do some thing like this, this should run every 1 min for 3 website or sub directories . **Note: It depends on your path**.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/first/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/second/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/third/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&
```

Let me know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Is mytrendin.com on the same Server as abc.com?

Comment: Edited please check once

Comment: Yes, you can run a cron job as cron jobs run on the server. What do you want your cronjob to do?

Comment: I want to send an email to admin on a particular date... is it possible?

Comment: but the problem is how do i code for different subdirectories?

Comment: Schedule the cron job for a specific time, for example every 5 minutes, then inside the cronjob you can put logic that specifies what you need to do. For instance, if it's the 3rd week of the month then you email the administrator of www.abc.com/third. Does that make sense?

Comment: but how do I schedule a cronjob for every subdirectory as there would be thousands of subdirectories in future...